# find common elements of two arrays if array size is big > memory available

Tags: algorithm, collections

There are several ways to solve this problem using sorting O(mlog(n)) or Hashing O(m+n) with extra space O(m) or O(n) or index increment method in O(m+n).

But I am more interested if there is limited memory and my arrays size is in the range of millions.

We can divide array A or B into segments and load it into memory but I was wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: By "intersection" do you mean the set of objects that are members of both arrays, assuming they are sorted (as in your title)?  If so this can be accomplished using minimal memory holding only one from each array at a time.

Comment: edited my question to make it more clear..

Comment: If the arrays are already sorted, as your title implies, this is trivial with minimal memory.

Comment: @jim garrison you are right.. this is trivial but if its unsorted then arrays should be sorted by "external sorting" technique and then apply the same logic on those sorted arrays.. please answer this i will close this question

Comment: If the arrays are unsorted then there are no shortcuts.  The options you give are all good. If the datasets are HUGE (tens of gigabytes) then external sorting will be the easiest and simplest option since there are already plenty of good sort programs available.

Answer (score 2):

The [element distinctness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_distinctness_problem) problem (which is at least as hard as your problem) is `O(nlogn)` without using any extra space.

However, using hashing solutions that can actually be improved on average case.

Your suggested approach is actually one of the ways to implement [intersection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_%28set_theory%29) in Database systems:

Create `k` buckets (on disk), and iterate over the lists, and add each element `e` to `bucket[hash(e)]`. 

Once you are done, assuming there is enough space so each bucket is small enough to be loaded to memory<sup>1</sup>, you only need to load `bucket[i]` for each list - and do in memory intersection (based on sort & iterate) for each bucket.

The result will yield you the answer for the intersection - which is common elements.

---

Another way it (intersection) is done in data base systems is by using [external sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting) (usually a variation of merge sort) and iterating, or creating an index optimized for disks (such as [B+ trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B+_tree)).

---

(1) It is usually the case, if it is not - repeat the process for each bucket (with different hash function) until you have small enough buckets.

Answer (score 1):

If the array are sorted, just walk through arrays simultaneously and copy common elements. In case of big arrays, load parts of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an external merge sort to sort with limited RAM.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting